# PayPal and Forms not working

Tags: php, forms, paypal

I've recently redesigned a site I'd originally built 2/3 years back. We used PayPal buttons for Gift Vouchers and Deposits, but neither are working on the new version.

One of the pages affected is http://www.louiseballantine.com/giftvouchers.php - you'll see that the buttons display properly, but nothing happens when clicked.

However, the old version of the page (and I've added the same code for the new button) works perfectly: http://www.louiseballantine.com/giftvouchers_old.php

Here is the code for the first button (copied and pasted from PayPal):

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="497ZF2RU65YJQ">
<input type="image" src="http://www.louiseballantine.com/img/voucher05.png" border="0" width="100%" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

As I said previously, there's also an issue with the contact forms, so this may not be a specific problem with the PayPal code. However, any assistance would be gratefully received.

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing in that form is a button. You must have some JS code to go with this that you lost.

Comment: Hi, we're not going to debug your code for you - you'll have to give us a bit more detail on what's going wrong before we can help you. What do the paypal example forms look like and how does your form differ from them? Do you get errors in the javascript console? What research did you do on this problem and what were the results?

Comment: The code I included is exactly what PayPal's button creator provided. However, I noticed that part of the bootstrap template included some JS files for form handling and, after removing those inserts, both the online forms and PayPal buttons now work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by removing bootstrap's integrated form-handling scripts.